# Set Text of TextView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, layout, icons

In my ListView, I save my data like this:

```
public void listview_fuellen(){
    DBHelper db = new DBHelper(this);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvKinder);
    Cursor c = db.select();
    int count = c.getCount();

    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
    List<String> auswahl = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> auswahl1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$1" + c.getCount());
    while(c.moveToNext())
    { 

        auswahl.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        auswahl1.add(" " + i);
        System.out.println("SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" + auswahl.get(i).toString());

        i++;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.firstLine, auswahl);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_black_text,R.id.secondLine, auswahl1);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Now, I tried the layout for my listview from here:

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.at/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-1.html

Now, how can I set values for the second line in each ListView-Item or the icon?

**EDIT:**

I tried it like this now, but there are no entries in my listview then.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map =  new HashMap<String, String>();;




    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$1" + c.getCount());
    while(c.moveToNext())
    { 
        //map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("name",c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name")));
        map.put("datum", c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("zeit")));


        i++;
    }
    mylist.add(map);

   SimpleAdapter mSchedule = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, R.layout.list_black_text, new String[] { "datum",
         "name" }, new int[] { R.id.firstLine, R.id.secondLine });

    lv.setAdapter(mSchedule);
    setListAdapter(mSchedule);
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: use a custom listview witha custom adapter

Comment: Can you show me an example? Like you see, I tried with another adapter but when I add it to the listview, only one of them is shown

Comment: Here is a really good explanation how to use adapters and which one is the best : http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Comment: So you think with ArrayAdpater this isn´t possible?

Comment: If you implement a custom array adapter and inflate a custom view, you then override getView and set the text in the getView method. You should look into the ViewHolder pattern when using the creating a custom listview adapter. Here is a nice tutorial of a listview, with a custom view, custom adapter and the viewholder pattern. http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/android-listview-tutorial.html

Comment: Can you look at my edit please? Tried your suggestion and used SimpleAdapter but it still doesn´t work.

Answer (score 0):

for that you can make a custom adapter and then you can set values for the second line in each ListView-Item.

You can check this link 
http://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Comment: Can you look at my edit please? Tried your suggestion and used SimpleAdapter but it still doesn´t work.